# Port ArcGIS Engine to ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF?

Tags: arcgis-engine, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

We have a WPF application, which has arcengine controls embedded in it. We are looking at options to replace ArcGIS Engine with someother component which is 64 bit and we are evaluating ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF (possibly .net as well).

We do not need an ArcGIS for Server or ArcGIS Online based solution, we dont use web maps or tiles services. We have file geodatabases and need to create, edit and modify feature classes within the gdb.

1**. Can I use ArcGIS Runtime SDKs to build a non-cloud / non - server WPF Solution.i.e. The map control in the WPF sdk will need to access only a local fgdb (not hosted as a service).**

Comment: As it stands your Question contains two questions that are only loosely related.  Consequently, I think it is too broad and recommend that you edit it so that only the question more important to you.  The other one can then be researched/asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the options that you are evaluating are good solutions, we already have been working in something very similar application, and we choose ArcGIS runtime for WPF about a year ago, right now we are thinking to migrate to ArcGIS runtime .NET.